# Regex, how to write query

Tags: java, regex

How to write a regular expression with the following text, which draws the text and number:

```
String txt = "Map. 12. txt Map. 13. txt Map. 14 txt ";
```

I tried to write the regex in the following way:

```
 String regex = "(Map\\p{Punct}\\p{Space}])([0-9]+\\p{Punct})(.+)?(Map)";
```

After the distribution receives: (Map. 12.) (Txt) (Map), which causes the next partition starts from Map. 14. skipping the text contained
between Map 13 and Map 14.

Thank for your help.

Comment: What is the square bracket after `\p{Space}` doing there?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
String s = "String txt = \"Map. 12. txt Map. 13. txt Map. 14 txt ";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(Map\\p{Punct}\\p{Space})([0-9]+\\p{Punct})(.+?)\\s*(?=Map|$)").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
Map. 12. txt 
Map. 13. txt
```

This won't match the `Map. 14 txt` because there isn't a punctuation exists next to the number 14. If you want to match this also, you need to make the punctuation pattern as optional like,

```
"(Map\\p{Punct}\\p{Space})([0-9]+\\p{Punct}?)(.+?)\\s*(?=Map|$)"
```